# "Cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been having this problem since I tried android programming(newbie here). Recently started Android Programming 2 weeks ago.
Testing this out(http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/225-lesson-19-creating-a-simple-calculator.html)
 and got problems on the part with R.id sample: R.id.etNum1

"etNum1 cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Here's my code:

```
    etNum1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNum1);
    etNum2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNum2);

    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnSub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSub);
    btnMult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMult);
    btnDiv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDiv);
```

XML for the buttons and text:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNum1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etNum2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSub"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Subtract" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Multiply" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDiv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Divide" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:text="Add" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="Answer"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably you are importing the `android.R` class instead of your application's `R` class

Instead of this

```
import android.R;
```

import this

```
import yourPackage.R;
```

Comment: Worked but having new problems after it. Thanks though! My problem now is opening the app. Thank you sir! Cheers!

Comment: @user2564966 you are welcome.. and also welcome to so. If you think the answer was helpful you can accept upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You also can `Clean` (Project ->Clean...) up your project to regenerate `R file` and see if it solved the problem.

Comment: when "there is no light at the end of the tunnel..." wait... Project->Clean always solves the inexplicable ! the only problem is I rarely remember this.. It is like more than a year that I used this last time... I wonder if it could fully clean whenever we start eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

R does not recognize etNum1. Build your code. It will work like magic. Because R will get updated after build